# Command cURL to PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to convert this part of the command cURL to PHP cURL:

```
-H 'Accept: application/json'
```

to

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
```

However adding that causes the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to not post.

Answer (score 1):

**Content-Type** and **Accept** are two different headers. Instead of setting a the content-type, try this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
```